# In angular2 how do you navigate to another route that requires an id?

Tags: angular

In angular2 how do you navigate to another route that requires an id?

I'm using this router version: **"@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1"**

**This is my app.component route I want to navigate to:**

```
{ path: '/blog/:slug', component: BlogArticle, as: 'BlogArticle' }
```

**This is my other component trying to navigate to it:**

```
this.router.navigate(['blog', { slug: blogId }]);
```

Basically I want to know how to navigate to a url with an id from the component and in a view.

**Current attempt in the view:**

```
[routerLink]=" ['/blog', {slug: blogId }]"
```

**Current attempt in the component:**

this.router.navigate(['blog', { slug: blogId }]);

Both attempts above didnt work and I got the following error:

**Error: Uncaught (in promise): Cannot match any routes.**

Its strange because I set my route link this in my app.component:

```
@Routes([
{ path: '/blog/:slug', component: BlogArticle, as: 'BlogArticle' }
])
```

Comment: Try removing `as: 'BlogArticle'` from [Route](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Route-class.html) definition, it might be wrong syntax with RC1 router.

Comment: Okay I will try tonight

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Having this route:

```
{ path: '/blog/:slug', component: BlogArticle }
```

You can navigate to your blog from the view with the following:

```
[routerLink]="['/blog', blogId]"
```

Or you can navigate to it from your component:

```
this.router.navigate(['/blog', blogId]);
```

Now that being said, you have to decide if *blogId* is an optional segment of your blog route or it is in fact required. If it is required then the code above is the way to go but if it is optional and may or may not be always present then I suggest to change your route to the following:

```
{ path: '/blog', component: BlogArticle }
```

And then if you want to navigate to your blog with a *blogId* then you can do so like this:

```
[routerLink]="['/blog', { blogId: id }]"
```

Comment: I have 2 routes for blog in the app.component: 

@Routes([
{ path: '/blog', component: BlogArticle, as: 'BlogArticle' }
{ path: '/blog/:slug', component: BlogArticle, as: 'BlogArticle' }
])

Comment: Would either of those routes pose a problem

Comment: Yes, if that's the case and you can go to the blog page without an Id then go with the second approach: Remove the route `/blog/:slug` and send the id as an optional parameter just like how I showed in my answer.

Comment: What would the @routes path look like for this?

Comment: Just this: `{ path: '/blog', component: BlogArticle }`. Since BlogId is optional, we are not going to put it on the path but we still can pass it if we want to.

Comment: What would the router link look like for that?

Comment: `[routerLink]=" ['/blog', { blogId: id }]"`

Comment: Thank you, I will test this out in a few hours

Comment: Sure, looking forward to the results :)

Comment: Can you provide some more details please?

Comment: These are my routes:   { path: '/register', component: Register},
  { path: '/register/:id', component: Register},

Comment: And how do you navigate to them?